# php mail not working perfectly with outlook

Tags: php, outlook

I have a problem using PHP to send mail. The mail is received by Outlook correctly, but it does not show the "From" address in the e-mail.

```
$subject = $_POST['message_subject'];
$message = $_POST['speaker_description'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$option  = $_POST['sel_reg_options'];
$email   = substr_replace($email ,"",-1);

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From:My Name<myifno@mysite.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Registration of Interest<info@mysite.com>\r\n";          
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$mail_sent = @mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving a space after the `:`?

Comment: yeah tried a space but still nothing is useful i have google it so much now i am sick with it

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose the name in double quotes (this also applies to the Reply-To address name):

```
$headers .= "From: \"My Name\" <myifno@mysite.com>\r\n";
```

Also, if running PHP on Unix, add the FROM envelope to the `$additional_parameters` parameter:

```
$mail_sent = @mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers,'-f myifno@mysite.com');
```

On the contrary, if running on Windows, set the `sendmail_from` INI directive either in `php.ini` or by using:

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'myifno@mysite.com');
```

**Sources:** [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), [php.net user comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#72715), [IBM sendmail command reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/sendmail.htm)

Comment: no guys its still the same in gmail the message is showing perfectly but outlook is not showing send address

Comment: Could you tell me which server (apache, IIS) and OS are you running PHP on?

Comment: Also, could you try placing your headers is this order? (From, MIME, Content, Reply-to).  Finally, check that the first `$header` call does not append data (i.e. `=` instead of `.=`).

Would be nice to remove the `@` when calling `mail()` to see possible errors/warnings.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help at the end i use php mailer and its working fine .

Answer (score 0):

I just recently switched my email scripts to [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It has made creating and sending emails much easier. I no longer worry about incorrect headers and the intricacies around PHP and email. I haven't had any issues formatting emails so that they are received correctly in the several email clients out there either.